# jQuery / css target nth-child class

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

```
<div class="outercontainer">
 <div class="paddedcontainer">

  <div class="pageheader">
   <div class="titlestyle"><h2>Fixed Title1</h2></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="grouped">
    <div class="col4">
    Some content
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="pageheader">
   <div class="titlestyle"><h2>Fixed Title2</h2></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
  Some other content not in a col4 div
  </div>
  <div class="row">
  Some other content not in a col4 div
  </div>


 </div>
</div>
```

Hi all, this is my first post here - I apologise for bringing my stupid question to you all but I am having a hard time trying to solve this on my own.

I would like to target the div class 'row' that does not have it's content in a col4 div.
I have tried using css nth-child but this does not seem to work and I have looked at jQuery .find .has .filter but I always end up targeting the upper most .row or none of the .row

I cannot change the html in anyway, all I can use is javascript or css.

Please help.

Many thanks,
Dazza

Comment: do u mean u want to target all the div with class row, that **DOESNOT** have a child with a class col4?

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
$('.row').not(':has(.col4)')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/PrB9B/)

[.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) : For filtering out matched elements from passed set
[:has()](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) : For filtering elements which has elements matching the passed selector

Comment: & the truth shall set you free :)
That is it - you have no idea how frustrating that was and you solved it in a nanosecond.
Cheers!

Comment: @user2519486 please accept this(an) answer, if you problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and a nested [`:has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/):

```
var rows = $('.row:not(:has(.col4))');
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/A6fnS/)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's [`:has`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) and the negation [`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) will in combination work for your purpose:

```
var $filtered = $(".row:not(:has(.col4))");
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Eq669/)

Answer (score -1):

This could work for your specific example:

```
var rows = $('.row').first().nextAll();
```